# Beginner: My swift code wont run on the side of playground even though it gives no error?

Tags: swift

Everything runs smoothly untill the last two lines where no output happens. No error messages apear either. I do not know why.

```
import Cocoa

func bankVault(passcode: String) -> Void {
    func OpenVault(Void) -> Void {
        println( "Vault Opened")
    }

    func CloseVault(Void) -> Void {
        println("Vault Closed")
    }

    if passcode == "secret" {
        OpenVault()
    } else {
        CloseVault()
    }
}

bankVault("secret")

bankVault("notSecret")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following thefredelement, he's correct but I did get an output within playground. I commented out "import Cocoa" cause it was giving me an error. But the running the passcode in bankVault, printed out. I commented them out to see if it was an error and it did not run when they where commented out.

[image]

Comment: i got the same ouput you got but its the last two lines where no output occurs. I dont think impot Cocoa is the problem either

Comment: yeah, those won't print out or do anything. They are just "instructions" to your bankVault method. They are simply telling your method what to run. They are inputs.

Comment: @Joesalad `bankVault` returns `Void`. What did you expect to be printed? :)

Comment: then what should I change void to, to make it print. I thought I was supposed to put void because I wasnt returning anything, just printing. I tried using String instead of Void but it said I got an error "Missing return in a function expected to return string."

Comment: @whereisleo I thought that the second two last line would pass "secret" into bankVault. Then the function would go through the if-else statement and realize secret (the passcode) == secret and then call the function OpenVault(). The OpenVault function would then  print "Vault Opened".

Comment: @whereisleo never mind i realized that the output did occur but the output didnt need to be right next to the last two lines. Instead it showed the output next to the function. thanks a bunch